# How to set a delay before a specific test in Chrome Postman?

Tags: twitter, postman

I'm learning Chrome Postman app and I'm using Twitter's API to do so.

What I'm doing is: I'm posting a post and then searching for it by its content.

**My problem for now is:** if I search the post by content right after posting it then my API request doesn't return this post. But if I wait about 10 seconds then my request works well.

**My guess is** that something goes on the Twitter server that delays my post appearing in the search.

So I want to wait a few seconds before the test that sends request to search my post. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a 10 seconds wait in pre-request script section of your Get request:

```
  var date = new Date();
  var curDate = null;
  do {
    curDate = new Date();
  }
  while (curDate - date < 10000);
```